# Navigation Drawer not loading layout with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I have my Events.java and event.xml layout, which has a recycler view & works fine when if I load the Event class directly. It looks like this:

[image: events.xml with RecyclerView]

However, if I load the navigation drawer, which then load the event.xml file, then I get the following screens with this error: "No adapter attached; skipping layout".

[image]

My issues is that why is the navigation menu not working and the event layout file not loading? As for my code, I think the following might be helpful.

**Events.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.events_rv_list);
    EventsAdapter eventsAdapter = new EventsAdapter(this, eList, this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(eventsAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}
```

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Events"
    android:background="#ffff6c">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/events_rv_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**NavigationDrawer.java**

```
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. There's not enough information here to determine the issue. What is `Events`? Is that an `Activity`? What is `NavigationDrawer`, and how does it relate to, and load, the "event layout file"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found the solution. The error was that the adapter was not attached to the RecyclerView.

In the first picture, the adapter worked because it was stored in a normal layout file (non fragment) class, so the onCreate was being called from the events.java. Events.java then loaded the layout (events.xml) and also attached the adapters to the RecyclerView like so:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id._events_recyclerview);

ADAPTE_CLASS adapter = new ADAPTE_CLASS(PASS DATA IF NECESSARY);

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
```

Now same thing can be applied in a Fragment where you can add the above code to onCrateView method (with relevant class names & ids). So that's **how you set a recyclerview adapter in a fragnent**.

Hope that helps.